# Is the comment here in the source code of Opencv wrong?

Tags: c++, opencv

When I'm reading the the source code of the function `imread()` in OpenCV, I find that there is a  comment ahead of the return line: **/// return a reference to the data**.
I think this comment is wrong here? Since `img` here is a local variable, and it expires after this funcion call so we can't return its reference. Plus: the return value of the definetion is `Mat` not `Mat &`(I'm a beginner of C++ so maybe this question is a little stupid?This function locates in `opencv/modules/imgcodecs/src/loadsave.cpp`)

```
Mat imread( const String& filename, int flags )
{
    CV_TRACE_FUNCTION();

    /// create the basic container
    Mat img;

    /// load the data
    imread_( filename, flags, img );

    /// optionally rotate the data if EXIF' orientation flag says so
    if( !img.empty() && (flags & IMREAD_IGNORE_ORIENTATION) == 0 && flags != IMREAD_UNCHANGED )
    {
        ApplyExifOrientation(filename, img);
    }

    /// return a reference to the data
    return img;
}
```

Comment: What is the declaration of class `Mat`? Does it perhaps function as a reference/handle semantic type, by containing references/handles to data allocated with longer lifetime? Then the comment would be correct (in a non-literal sense).

Comment: This is just a colloquial -- `img` references the underlying image data. That's what you use it for.

Comment: Oh My! That souds resonable!Thanks(A stupid question indeed -_-)

Comment: @DanilHu Not a stupid question at all. It shows you understand what you are reading and the question is as reasonable as the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

It seems this is maybe poor wording. You are right, this is not a C++ reference and the object will for sure be copied by value.

But I think the author of the comment may have referred to the data itself, which is handled inside `Mat`. But this is not entirely obvious from these few lines of code.

It still is poor wording and leads to this kind of confusion.